# p2p audioconferencing and desktop sharing in java

Tags: java, p2p, audio-streaming, rdp, desktop-sharing

I am going to submit a proposal of project in university..

**Overview**

I am going to make a project in which multiple participants can join a meeting and meeting organizer share his desktop with all participants.

participants can access organizers desktop it depends on organizer to who he gives his desktop control..

only one participant can access organizer desktop at one time while others are siting and watching the video stream of organizer desktop and waiting for their turn.

all participants can talk to each other simultaneously.

the whole system working in p2p environment.

**I need an experts opinion on**

1) Suggested API's for p2p communication that works for above scenario.?

2) Suggested topics in which i should do research to achieve audio chat among participants in p2p environment.?

3) Any other prerequisites that i should aware of before start writing code.?

4) Any limitation of Java programing language.?

5) Any other ideas to make my project better.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [BBB](https://github.com/bigbluebutton) it's an open source project.

Answer (score 0):

1) Suggested API's for p2p communication that works for above scenario.?

JXTA

2) Suggested topics in which i should do research to achieve audio chat among participants in p2p environment.?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html

3) Any other prerequisites that i should aware of before start writing code.?

NAT Traversal,p2p strategies like hole punching,TCP,UDP

4) Any limitation of Java programing language.?

for your scenario no limitation its completely possible in java..

5) Any other ideas to make my project better.?

well if you have time make an android version too..